# Calculate the maximum rotation angle of a rectangle to overlap a smaller rectangle within a fixed distance

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, rotations, rectangles

I'm trying to figure out how far a rectangle can rotate from its center while still overlapping a smaller rectangle given vertical and horizontal constraints

[Rectangle overlap without rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzzMF.png)

[Rectangle overlap with rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MU8XP.png)

I need to figure out the range that the black rectangle can rotate + move while still fitting over a certain amount of the blue rectangle. Basically, I am trying to solve for the maximum offset the black rectangle can have while meeting these conditions.

V1 can be between 0 and 20 cm

H1 can be between 0-9 cm

Any feedback for what equations I need to use or resources that might help me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a tough question.  But it can solved numerically with the aid of a computer program, and an iterative scheme such the Newton-Raphson multivariate method, or a similar method.  Basically your variables are the horizontal displacement and the vertical displacement of the center of the black rectangle, and also the rotation angle of the black rectangle about it center, then for each set of $\Delta x, \Delta y, \theta $ you need to write a software function to calculate the common area between the two rectangles.

Comment: Every rectangle is overlap of two stripes. Every stripe is given by two linear inequalities. So overlapping region of two rectangles is solution of set of 8 linear inequalities.